# Pseudocode - Arrays - Maxrun

Tags: arrays, algorithm, max, pseudocode

I'm trying to solve a problem but I have difficulties with algorithms.
I have to write pseudocode for an iterative algorithm maxRun(A) that takes an array A of integer as input and return the maximal length of a run in A.
The subarray `A[k...l]` is a run if `A[j] <= A[j + 1]` for all j where `k <= j < l`. So it is a non decreasing segment of A.
Ex. A = [1,5,2,3,4,1], the max length would be 3 [2,3,4].
Thanks.

Comment: I suggest searching using the term "longest increasing subsequence". You should get lots of results that way :-)

Comment: So what have you got so far ?  By failing to show us anything at all you raise the suspicion that you are looking for someone to do all the work for you.

Comment: Thanks Kevin.
Mark I have done something completely wrong, it doesn't work, I have written "I have difficulties with algorithms" so please respect the nature of stackoverflow. If you can give me a helping hand ok.

Comment: Split your algorithm into 2 parts. One is to find the length of a run starting from position k (hint: requires a loop). The second part is to find the length of the run for every position 0..l (hint: this is another loop and it uses the loop of part 1) while updating the currently known max length in case it is greater than the one already known.

Answer (score 0):

Simple Java implementation:

```
public class FindRun {
    public static int maxRun(int[] a) {
        int max = 0;
        int index = 0;
        int previous = a[0] + 1;
        int run = 0;
        while (index < a.length) {
            if (a[index] >= previous) {
                run++;
            } else {
                max = Math.max(max, run);
                run = 1;
            }
            previous = a[index];
            index++;
        }
        return Math.max(max, run);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       System.out.println(maxRun(new int[] { 1, 5, 2, 3, 4, 1 }));
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution similar to @Michael's, in Ruby:

```
a = [1,5,2,3,4,1]     

r = [1]
(1...a.size).each { |i| r << ((a[i] == a[i-1] + 1) ? r[i-1] + 1 : 1) }
r.max          #=> 3
r.index(r.max) #=> 4
```

indicating the the maximum run is of length 3 and ends at `a` offset 4; that is, the run 2,3,4.  I will now explain the algorithm I used.  For those who don't know Ruby, this will also give you a taste of the language:

- `r = [1]` creates an array with one element, whose value is `1`.  This is read, "The longest run ending at `a` offset `0` is of length `1`.
- `(1...a.size)` is the sequence 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.  Three dots between `1` and `a.size` means the sequence ends with `a.size - 1`, which is 5.
- `each` causes the following block, enclosed by `{}` to be executed once for each element of the sequence.  The block variable `i` (in `|i|`) represents the sequence element.
- `r << x` means add `x` to the end of the array `r`.
- the expression to the right of `r <<` says, "if the element of `a` at index `i` is one greater than element of `a` at index `i-1`, then the length of the run ending at index `i` is one greater than the length of the run ending at index `i-1`; else, a new run begins, whose length at offset `i` is 1.

After `each` is finished:

```
# r => [1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1]
```

All that is required now is to find the element of `r` whose value is greatest:

```
r.max          #=> 3
```

and the associated index:

```
r.index(r.max) #=> 4
```

Actually, the code above would more typically be written like this:

```
(1...a.size).each_with_object([1]) {|i,r| r << a[i] == a[i-1]+1 ? r[i-1]+1 : 1}
start, length = r.index(r.max) + 1 - r.max, r.max #=> 2, 3
```

Alternatively, we could have made `r` a hash (call it `h`) rather than an array, and written:

```
 (1...a.size).each_with_object({0 => 1}) {|i,h|
   h[i] = a[i] == a[i-1]+1 ? h[i-1]+1 : 1}.max_by {|_,v| v} #=> [4, 3]
```